# WPF Using multiple Resource Dictionaries from multiple projects

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have two class Library projects:
Project A.Themes
Project B.Themes

Project A.Themes is my base Themes Project.
Project B.Themes using A.Themes and have new styles and some of the resources have keys that already defined in A.Themes.

We want to use this two themes in our Project, and if we use a resource that is defined in both of the project we want to take the resource from B.Themes.

This is our code:

A.Themes have few files of styles:

```
Brushes.xaml
Buttons.xaml
CheckBox.xaml
```

etc..

we load them in Bundle.Xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>         
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/A.Themes;component/Assets/Brushes.xaml"/>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/A.Themes;component/Assets/Buttons.xaml"/>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/A.Themes;component/Assets/CheckBox.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

B.Themes have the same Files:

```
Brushes.xaml
Buttons.xaml
CheckBox.xaml
```

we load them in Bundle.Xaml and adding the bundle of A.Themes:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>         
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/A.Themes;component/Bundle.xaml"/>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/B.Themes;component/Assets/Brushes.xaml"/>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/B.Themes;component/Assets/Buttons.xaml"/>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/B.Themes;component/Assets/CheckBox.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

In our Project we load them in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/A.Themes;component/Bundle.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/B.Themes;component/Bundle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

the problems are:
1. it not always takes the resources from B.Themes and we can't find out why.
2. if i remove the reference to A.Themes/Bundle.xaml from app.xaml the project can't find resources from A.Themes even though it's included in B.Themes/Bundle.xaml

note:
we have refernce to A.Themes project in B.Themes
and refernce to A.Themes and B.Themes in main project

can someone please help me to understande what is going on here?
thanks!

Comment: My guess: you may have silent exceptions on merging resource dictionaries, as you have resource names overlapping. Once I had something like that (though the error source was different), and I decompiled the app with IlSpy. It didn't manage to decompile some resource dictionaries (or it did partially, don't remember now) which helped me to track the root cause.

Comment: i see that i have error "value cannot be null. paramerter name: item". in the line of loading A.Themes/Bundle.xaml in B.Themes/Bundle.xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loading order isn't quite what you expect. From MSDN:

> Resources in a merged dictionary occupy a location in the resource lookup scope that is just after the scope of the main resource dictionary they are merged into

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/merged-resource-dictionaries

So the dictionaries that merge into `Bundle.xaml` of assembly A are actually loaded after the other ones.

Please refer to the following link for more information and an example of the same behaviour: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3bea80f9-d1db-4cb7-ae7a-77a02eaf4ec9/resourcedictionary-load-order?forum=wpf

Comment: "So the dictionaries that merge into Bundle.xaml of assembly A are actually loaded after the other ones." that's what i want that will happen, but it doesn't

Comment: No, this is not what you want. You want the B dictionaries to be loaded after A ones, don't you?

Comment: oopes, yeah. sorry, but i didn't understood what i should do

Comment: Merge all dictionaries in App.xaml?

Comment: you mean to take all files from the bundles to the app.xaml? like this: <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>         
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/A.Themes;component/Assets/Brushes.xaml"/>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/B.Themes;component/Assets/Brushes.xaml"/>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/A.Themes;component/Assets/CheckBox.xaml" /> Source="pack://application:,,,/B.Themes;component/Assets/CheckBox.xaml" /> 
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: still, not working.. it takes the style from A.Themes

Comment: You need to remove the merged dictionaries.

Comment: The property "Resources" can only be set once.

Comment: Yes. So set it once? I meant remove the merged dictionaries from the other files.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i don't understand. can you please add full example?

Comment: Just get rid of all <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> except for the element in App.xaml. Read the thread I linked to for more information.

Comment: thanks, it works! the only problem that we need to order the 35 files in the order of using brushes, then textblocks, then buttons etc..

Comment: The order always matters when working with resources.