# Exception: Cannot find resource named '*'. Resource names are case sensitive

Tags: wpf, new-project

But why. I see to be correct how the file works:

Error in IFocus.xaml but the converter is defined before.
I don't understant what is wrong.

Referance: Modern.xaml
Is a referance from another project. and i like this.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Modern.Converters">

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="C_FocusBush" Color="Red"/>
<c:ThicknessConverter x:Key="ThicknessConverter"/>

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Interfaces/IFocus/IFocus.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The IFocus.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:i="clr-namespace:Modern.Interfaces">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type i:IFocus}" x:Key="{x:Type i:IFocus}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource C_FocusBush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type i:IFocus}">

                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness, Converter={StaticResource ThicknessConverter}"/>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The main app to include all resources:

```
<Application x:Class="*.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Modern;component/Modern.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

The brush works fine but the Converter not, why not?

Comment: You're using `StaticResource` to retrieve the converter, but `DynamicResource` to retrieve the brush. At a guess, that XAML is being parsed at a point in time before either resource has been added defined. `DynamicResource` doesn't mind; it sticks around and provides a value when the value becomes available (and remains on the scene, in case the value changes). `StaticResource` must provide a value right then, but it can't.

Comment: `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` appears below those two resource definitions in the text of your XAML file, but I would hesitate to take as a guarantee that the definitions in the XAML are actually parsed in that order.

Comment: How can i make that? Strange behavior.

Comment: If these resources are specific to that Style, put them in the same XAML file. If they're widely used "theme" resources, use `DynamicResource` to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is the `Style` in `IFocus.xaml` that references a `Brush` resource in `Modern.xaml`, it's `IFocus.xaml` that should merge `Modern.xaml` and not the other way around:

**Modern.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="C_FocusBush" Color="Red"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**IFocus.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Style ...>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource C_FocusBush}"/>
    </Style>

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Modern.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Modern;component/Interfaces/IFocus/IFocus.xaml"/>
```

Alternatively, you can create a separate resource dictionary with all brushes and merge this one and the one with the styles into `App.xaml` or another resource dictonary.

You may also want to see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687750/wpf-using-multiple-resource-dictionaries-from-multiple-projects/45691248#45691248) for more information about the order in which resource dictionaries are loaded.

Comment: Is not another method to merge the xaml in the referance and to include only one xaml in the App ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. You shouldn't define a style in `A` that references a resource in `B` without merging `B` into `A` because `A` does have a dependency upon `B`. If you don't want to merge, you should define the resource directly in `A`.

Comment: Or define the brushes in a separate dictionary and merge them both into `App.xaml`.

Comment: Like. A -> Merge: Brushes, IFocus, Etc..., B -> Merge A

Comment: If you merge `Brushes` and `IFocus` into `App.xaml`in that order, it should work.

Comment: I make in A: Variables with brushes, etc and Components with all Styles. And i merge both in B and work fine. Thanks. You can edit the post like this.

Comment: @And-RoMarian: I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered an error format the same like this after I changed my Visual Studio theme to custom (mine's OneMonokai). I just reverted it back to the default theme and surprisingly it was resolved. It may seem far from the question but you can try this fix if you want.

Comment: Changing to DarkGreen to Light resolved it for me. Strange one this. But Kelvin, thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you man, who would have tough changing the Theme was the issue