# Trying to set foreground text color from resourcedictionary

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a label style that applies a foreground color defined in a brushes resource directory.

```
<Color x:Key="TextForegroundColor" >#8B4513</Color>

<SolidColorBrush 
    x:Key="TextForegroundColorBrush"
    Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource TextForegroundColor}, Path=Color}" />
```

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="MVILabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextForegroundColorBrush}" />
</Style>
```

When I run the app, the foreground is not applied, but all of the others are.  What am I doing wrong?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Binding

```
Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource TextForegroundColor}, Path=Color}"
```

is wrong. It would require that a Color has a Color property.

You would either write

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource TextForegroundColor}}"/>
```

or just

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource TextForegroundColor}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I used what you said and now have :  <SolidColorBrush 
  x:Key="TextForegroundColorBrush"
  Color="{StaticResource TextForegroundColor}"/> ,   but still no color in the actual label.

Comment: No idea, are the SolidColorBrush and the Style declared in different ResourceDictionaries?

Comment: Add the former to the MergedDictionaries of the latter, e.g. like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45687750/1136211

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after three days of searching, removing things, I finally found one control that applied the styles and one that didn't.  In going step by step through each comparing things, I found a statement in the codebehind that disabled the control.  That's what was going on. It was disabled and there fore was showing the correct style.  I enabled the control, and bingo, styles applied.  Thanks to all who participated.