# How to load a ResourceDictionary from a different project with WPF and .Net 4.5?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two projects in a single solution

- Project1
- CommonComponents

I'm trying to write a theme that will be reused in various projects, and I have the file saved in `CommonComponents` under `Resources/Theme.xaml`.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687750/wpf-using-multiple-resource-dictionaries-from-multiple-projects) answer, in `Project1`, I added this to my main window's XAML file :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CommonComponents;Resources/Theme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

But it does not work, the app crashes when initializing the window.

Everywhere I look, the information either seem outdated, or it does not work. I do not understand why this does not work.

### ** Update **

This is the content of `Theme.xaml`, it's nothing much, I only wanted to test the import, first.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: `CommonCOmponents` != `CommonComponents`, maybe a simple type-o?

Comment: Nevermind the typo, it still does not work.

Comment: OK, with that out of the way, give me a few. What types are the projects?

Comment: `Project1` is a WPF .Net 4.5 and the other one was an originally empty project where I did add a reference to WPF. Note that I do successfully use `CommonComponents` to import WPF custom controls and behaviors.

Comment: Do you get any exception messages when the app crashes?  Also, it could be something in the Theme.xaml that is making it crash, such as a dependency that your Project1 cannot resolve. I would also recommend moving your MergedDictionaries from your MainWindow.xaml.cs and putting it into your App.xaml.cs, for broader use cases.

Comment: Can you show the `Theme.xaml` code, it should be an actual `ResourceDictionary`, otherwise the merge dictionary will not work. My `Source` looks like: `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CommonComponents;component/Resources/Theme.xaml" />` This means my `Theme.xaml` is inside another folder called `Resources` in the `CommonComponents` project.

Comment: @zaggler ah! comparing with your comment, I had `component` missing after the `;`. Adding that string now works. I do not recall reading anywhere that `component` must be present, followed by the path of the file inside the project.

Comment: Another simple type-o hahah, glad its working.

Comment: You can also do this sort of thing by putting your resource dictionary at (Core Project Library)\Themes\Generic.xaml and it will automatically be used throughout your core library without needing to be manually added to each xaml file and without needing to merge dictionaries at all. You can then add this file to your other projects by putting a reference to that file in the other assembly's App.xaml file like this:

<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YOUR CORE ASSEMBLY NAME;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `component` part.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CommonComponents;Resources/Theme.xaml" />
```

change to

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CommonComponents;component/Resources/Theme.xaml" />
```

and it now works.